# Typescript unknown options on vscode tasks file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using this tasks.json file in vscode:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

VsCode is telling me:

```
error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: '.'.
error TS5023: Unknown option 'p'
Use the '--help' flag to see options.
```

This is the project structure:

```
│   .gitignore
│   package.json
│   tsconfig.json
│
├───.vscode
│       settings.json
│       tasks.json
└───src
    │   configuration.ts
    │   index.ts
    │   variables.ts
    │
    ├───api
    │       api.ts
    │       UsersApi.ts
    │
    └───model
            models.ts
```

I've created a public repository in order for you to be able to take a look on there. [Here you can see the files](https://github.com/jeusdi/swagger-client).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the task is picking up an earlier version of `tsc`. I believe the `-p` flag was added in Typescript 1.5.

To check this, try using the following `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["--version"]
}
```

Then check the output window in vscode: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>

This displays which version of TypeScript is being picked up.

To get a new version of TS, you can either:

- Update your globally installed version of TypeScript: `npm install -g typescript`
- Or install TypeScript locally `npm install typescript` and use `"command": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"` in the `tasks.json`

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I don't know why system is picking an old version (1.0.3) since I installed the newer version globally (`npm list -g depth=0 prints me out: typescript@2.0.10`), any ideas?. Now, it's telling me that "." is not a recognozible external command...